# Node Js Express validator Check if field is numeric only if it is not empty

Tags: node.js, express

I use express-validator to check my post fields, one of my field must be a decimal or empty. I used this Schema:

```
request.checkBody({ 
        'product_price': {
            optional: true,
            isDecimal: {
                errorMessage: 'The product price must be a decimal'
            }
        }
})
```

The problem with this Schema is to not validate my post if product_price is empty, even with "optional: true".

Comment: First things first. `optional: true, // won't validate if field is empty`. But from your question it seems like you are assuming the opposite is true, a typo perhaps?

Comment: And have you tried `notEmpty: true`? This is all directly from the [readme](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) so sorry if I'm repeating obvious things.

Comment: Actually with this Schema, the form is not validate if the product_price is empty; witch is not my need. I want it to be checked (decimal  or not) only if is not empty.
Can you develop what is typo??

Comment: This the scenario needed:
product_price : '' //validation OK
product_price: 25.25 //validation OK
product_price: 'ABC' //validation NOK

Comment: @ippi Maybe I misunderstood the question. I changed the title

Comment: No sorry, it's my reading skills that are sub par. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the [`checkFalsy`](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#optional-input) option for `optional` to allow defined-but-empty values:

```
request.checkBody({ 
  'product_price': {
    optional: {
      options: { checkFalsy: true }
    },
    isDecimal: {
      errorMessage: 'The product price must be a decimal'
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: the documentation has been moved since posting this answer, it can now be found [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#existsoptions).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone is using `express-validator` body. You can do the following thing

```
router.post('apiname', [
  body('product_price').trim()
    .optional({ checkFalsy: true })
    .isNumeric().withMessage('Only Decimals allowed'),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using `req.checkBody('optionalParam', 'optionalParam must be a number').optional().isNumber();`

Comment: number doesnt exist in the current version :D